# Linking files / header files in C

Tags: c

I have 2 c files (& their header files). I have included the function "put" in the corresponding header, but I still have the following errors, when I input "**gcc -o main main.c**" in the terminal.

> main.c:(.text+0x389): undefined reference to `put' collect2: error: ld
> returned 1 exit status

**may I know the reason? How should I modify my code?**

I tried to change the linking order in makefile but failed. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(.)

add_executable(Demo
        main.c main.h KeyValueStore.c KeyValueStore.h )
```

main.c

```
#include "main.h"
...
int main() {
...
   if (strcmp("PUT", tokens[0]) == 0) {
      put(tokens[1], tokens[2]);
...
}
```

main.h

```
...
#include "KeyValueStore.h"
...
```

KeyValueStore.c

```
#include "KeyValueStore.h"

#define BUFSIZE 1024

typedef struct KeyValueStore {
    char key[BUFSIZE];
    char value[BUFSIZE];
} KV_Store;
KV_Store kvStore[BUFSIZE];

...

int put(char* key, char* value){
...
}
```

KeyValueStore.h

```
...
typedef struct KeyValueStore;
int put(char* key, char* value);
...
```

Comment: I think that's a linker error and I think you should `enable_language(C)` in your CMakeLists.txt I don't see you do so anywhere.
Also, CMake is a build system generator, we use it to generate Makefiles, so you have to tell CMake to use your `CMakeLists.txt` to generate a Makefile. You don't and you shouldn't run the command manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any .o files in that folder and delete them if you do. It's possible the compiler failed at some point while compiling which left *.o files that aren't linked properly

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I misread the question because for some reason it came up as a c++17 question for me. I'm not sure if what I said still applies to C though I do know it works with C++. Sorry about that to everyone that read my answer before I edited it

Not 100% sure if this is why you are having the error, though you need to put all .c files in the compiler.

So you currently are trying to "**gcc -o main main.c**" where instead you want to do something more like "**gcc -o main main.c keyValueStore.c**".

If you do not give the compiler every .c file, it won't have all the definitions and you will get an error similar to what you have.

I also don't really think you need main.h, assuming there isn't any more code in there, it really isn't worth having a whole extra file and instead just putting the #include in main.c.

Comment: Will `int *new = malloc(4*sizeof(int))` work in a .cpp file? I would call it really bad practice to put C code in a .cpp file. C is not C++. Also, there is nothing wrong with a `main.h` header and it is clearly not causing the problem.

Comment: Oh wait, I completely stuffed that up there. For some reason this post came up under the c++17 filter for me and I kinda just assumed the code was all c++. I think what I said about header files still applies though what I said about file types is completely my bad, sorry about that